# changing single field in multiple files in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a set of json config files that need to have all instances of a field "datasource" changed based on the contents of a variable
$GRAPHITEVOL. However, in each file there is a single instance of this field that must not change.

Directory structure with files to edit:

```
tree grafana
grafana
├── dashboards
│   ├── multicluster-noc-view.json
│   ├── solidfire-cluster.json
│   ├── solidfire-node.json
│   ├── solidfire-volume.json
│   ├── solidfire-volume-topn.json
│   ├── vsphere-esxi-metrics.json
│   └── vsphere-vm-stats.json
```

An example of the config file contents (snip from JSON blob):

```
"datasource": "-- Grafana --",     # <- this needs to be left alone
"datasource": "graphite-db-dev",   # <- Needs to be replaced with contents of $GRAPHITEVOL
```

Current solution from from a bash script:

```
DASHBOARDS=$(ls grafana/dashboards/*.json)
sed -i "s/graphite-db/$GRAPHITEVOL/g" $DASHBOARDS
```

So assuming $GRAPHITEVOL was set to "docker-vol-2" then the output after running the script would be:

```
"datasource": "-- Grafana --",  #Left unchanged
"datasource": "docker-vol-2",   #Field changed with contents of $GRAPHITEVOL
```

This works, but is very fragile since it won't handle a case where the datasource is anything but "graphite-db-dev". 
Ideally the sed statement would match/replace any value in the ["datasource": "docker-vol-2"] statement without touching
any line that matched  ["datasource": "-- Grafana --",]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This will replace everything which is not equal to `-- Grafana --`:

```
sed -i '/-- Grafana --/b; s/\("datasource": "\).*\(".*$\)/\1$GRAPHITEVOL\2/g' $DASHBOARDS
```

Comment: I had to modify it just a bit to work, but thanks so much!

sed -i '/-- Grafana --/b; s/\("datasource": "\).*\(".*$\)/\1'$GRAPHITEVOL'\2/g' $DASHBOARDS

Had to add the single quotes around '$GRAPHITEVOL' so it would get interpreted.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that! Sorry. I used the simple quotes around the sed command to use the double ones in the pattern... Thanks